# Getting error "ImportError: cannot import name SimplePool" when using restkit

Tags: python, rest, restkit

i am using:

```
from restkit import Resource,  SimplePool, BasicAuth, request
```

environment:

Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:03:08)

```
>>> restkit.version_info
(3, 3, 2)
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the changelog:

> `SimplePool` has been replaced by `TConnectionManager`

in [restkit 2.3](http://benoitc.github.com/restkit/news.html#id8).